# What are some web technologies that support reactive extensions over a network?

Tags: windows-runtime, system.reactive, communication

In RX you have observables and observers. So far I've dealt with those two conceptual elements being on the same machine. But what if they are separated by a LAN or even the internet? What are some options to transparently subscribe to an observable on a different machine? What technology can support this stream-subscribing behavior when there is a network in the way?

Specifically, my target platform is a WinRT app client and the server would be something running on a Windows machine.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. Care to provide a constructive reason so I can improve my question?

Comment: [help/on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: In other words, try rewording your question as "I want to do X. Here is how I tried to do X.  Tools Y and Z look like they can't do X.  What is a good way to do X?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently this is a very broad question and difficult to provide a helpful answer. I don't beleive that there is anything currently in the public space that allows for what you are asking i.e. Transparently exposing remote queries on an observable sequence. However Bart and the Rx/Bing/Cortana team at Microsoft have apparently got some internal software that does this.

To do this you really need to be able to serialize your queries and send them to the server. In the `IEnumerable<T>` world this translates to `IQueryable<T>` and the canonical example is LINQ-SQL/Entity Framework. In Rx `IObservable<T>` would map to `IQbservable<T>` (yes really), but implementations of this type are rare. I believe this is mainly due to the most people struggling with the learning curve that Rx presents, and don't want the extra layer of abstraction.

If you don't need the Transparent subscription, but just want to stream data from one server to another and cosume that with Rx, then you can do that with SignalR, WCF, Crossbar.IO/WAMP and I am sure many others. You may just need to put a tiny wrapper around the library, probably nothing more that an `Observable.Create`.

EDIT:

Here is an example of using Rx with Tibco's Rendevous (TibRv) communications stack.

https://github.com/LeeCampbell/RxCookbook/blob/master/IO/Comms/TibRv.md
and the code
https://github.com/LeeCampbell/RxCookbook/blob/master/IO/Comms/TibRvSample.linq

Comment: Thanks Lee. That last part (not the transparent I-Quabservable) is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: And sorry I failed to provide a sample of what and Rx wrapper around some duplex comms library would look like. Answer edited to include this now.

Comment: Thanks for the sample. I don't suppose you have an cookbook recipies for integrating SignalR with Rx? In my limited understanding of SignalR, wouldn't that be a more elegant alternative to TibRv for general purposes?

Comment: See Adpative's http://reactivetrader.com/ sample app for usages of Rx and SignalR in C# and Javascript.

Comment: Brilliant! Lee... you have just saved me weeks of work on my project. Thank you.